# How to send multiple gif files in Flask response?

Tags: python, flask

I need to send a dictionary of name and single/multiple .gif files as response using Flask. [flask.send_from_directory(directory, filename, **options)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory) works fine for single file but, couldn't find any function for multiple files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't send multiple files in a response. You'll need to either use multiple responses or send an archive file (e.g., zip, tar).

Comment: Or pull them from client side.